# openbox: how can i rearrange desktops

Tags: openbox

I am using openbox in archlinux

I have 5 virtual desktops

I have opened a set of windows in each desktop

now i want to work on desktop5

I want to bring `desktop 5` to first

i.e change desktop 5 as desktop 1 and change all others numbers accordingly

I have set the shortcut key for desktop 1 as `W-F1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Manjaro KDE and decided to try out openbox, and I was having the same issue - the way I fixed it was with the KDE system settings app, and just rearranging the displays in Hardware->Display Configuration.

You can download it from the AUR https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/systemsettings/. It may have only worked since I'm on manjaro KDE but its worth a try

Comment: You're correct: this only works if OpenBox is run on top of KDE. And installing the KDE system settings app on a system that has no KDE would pull in a lot of KDE infrastructure, which would be a waste of space if the original poster uses GNOME instead, or a lightweight OpenBox without any desktop environment at all.